# Convert SQL statement to LINQ with case condition

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a problem with converting a native select statement with CASE statement using LINQ.

This is the native SQL which is working in SQL Server :

```
select 
    v.vehl_ContainerNo as cont_name, v.vehl_Name,
    v.vehl_drivername, v.vehl_entrancedate, v.vehl_customsdec,
    c.Capt_AR as VehicleState,
    case 
       when v.vehl_rampid is null 
          then '' 
          else (select ramp_Name 
                from Ramp 
                where ramp_RampID = v.vehl_rampid) 
    end as cont_rampid
from 
    Vehicle v, Custom_Captions c
where 
    v.vehl_state = c.Capt_Code 
    and c.Capt_Family = 'vehl_state' 
    and v.vehl_ClearanceCompany = 471
```

I want to get the ramp_name:

- if vehl_rampid is null  then return an empty string
- else do another select statement to get the ramp_name from the ramp table where vehl_rampid equals ramp_rampid.

when i use the following linq statement:

```
//List<qryRslt> query = (from v in db.Vehicles
                    //                       join cus in db.Custom_Captions on v.vehl_state equals cus.Capt_Code
                    //                       join ram in db.Ramps on v.vehl_rampid equals ram.ramp_RampID
                    //                       where
                    //                       cus.Capt_Family == "vehl_state" && v.vehl_Deleted == null && v.vehl_ClearanceCompany == p.pusr_CompanyId
                    //                       select new qryRslt
                    //                       {
                    //                           vehl_ContainerNo = v.vehl_ContainerNo,
                    //                           vehl_Name = v.vehl_Name,
                    //                           vehl_drivername=v.vehl_drivername,
                    //                           vehl_entrancedate=v.vehl_entrancedate,
                    //                           vehl_customsdec=v.vehl_customsdec,
                    //                           VehicleState=v.vehl_state,
                    //                           cont_rampid=v.vehl_rampid==null?" ":ram.ramp_Name


                    //                       }).ToList();
```

it gives me an unexpected result that differs from native sql statement written in sql server

How can I implement sql statement with another sql in case statement?

Comment: Please add your attempted LINQ code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you returning. Let's assume you are trying to return class: `MyClass`

Then LINQ would looks something like:

```
List<MyClass> result = (from c in Vehicle
             from x in Custom_Captions
             join z in Ramp on c.vehl_rampId equals z.ramp_RampID
             where c.vehl_state == x.Capt_Code 
                  && x.Capt_Family == 'vehl_state' 
                  && c.vehl_ClearanceCompany == 471
             select new MyClass{
                  prop1 = c.vehl_rampid is null ? "" : z.ramp_Name
             }).ToList();
```

Above code is using `Object Initialiser` to define object by filling it's all properties.

Comment: This could well turn into the answer that the OP needs if you'd manage to add another `from...where...select` instead of `c.vehl_rampid`.

Comment: i tried to do that but it gives me different output against the sql server, when i tried to join ramps table on `v.vehl_rampid equals ram.ramp_RampID`,  and when select the following :
`cont_rampid=v.vehl_rampid==null?" ":ram.ramp_Name`

I think the problem is when i join the ramps with vehicle

Comment: thank you for updating your answer but the result differs from the one in sql server how can i do select statement in another sql statement ??

Comment: probably cause that query do inner joins. Are you expecting Vehicles that has not corresponding Custom_Captions?

Comment: I think that the problem from inner join, so in the native SQL i used to use two SQL statements, but i don't know how to implement this in LINQ